# Set storage location of MongoDB installed on AWS EC2 Instance to EBS storage. And How do I recover It after instance is stopped/terminated?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Hello everone I am new to AWS. I have created and Instance and installed MongoDB on It. But I learned from EC2 docs that the data stored on EC2 machine destroyed once they stop or terminated. So I have to use EBS for the data storage.

On the 4th step of creating EC2-Instance I selected the volume [image]

But I don't know how to use it. Is it automatically used by EC2-Instance to store the data in it or we have to manually do it.
I know that for changing the database storage we have to change the file named mongod.conf and modify the dbpath there but I don't know what path to give there. and after that also if I destroyed that instance when I will get the EBS storage back.
thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your screenshot the EBS volume is the root volume for the instance. So unless you add other volumes to the instance, everything persisted to disk on that instance is going to be stored on the EBS volume. You can pick (or create) any location to store your database.

Comment: ok, so you are saying it is the root volume instead of EBS volume in the question right? So what if I add another volume of EBS of General Purpose SSD then after What I have to do I am asking that.

Comment: In your screenshot the root volume **is** an EBS volume. If you added more volumes you would mount the volume in the OS, and then use the mount point as the location for your database. This is well documented already http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: hello @MarkB as you said I created an Volume and mount it to the directory called data, So now if I store my db to **data** folder then it will be stored on the EBS volume correct. Sorry I know its a embarrassing one but I am Extremely new to AWS and concern about the data. And one more thing what if my instance is in different region/sub-region and I want to connect to EBS volume which has data in it is there any way to do it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you mounted the EBS volume to /data, then files stored in /data will be on the EBS volume.

Answer (score 1):

After you have mounted the EBS volume correctly as per instructions [**here**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html), you can use the following steps to store your data to EBS volume.

- Edit mongod.conf file.
  `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`
- Change the line `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` to the new path storage location, e.g. `dbpath=/data/mongodb`
- Update the permissions of your chosen path to allow the MongoDB user to write to it, e.g. `chown $USER -R /home/user/data/mongodb`
  In most cases you user is mongodb. So you can replace `$USER` with **mongodb:mongodb**
- Restart the service
  `sudo service mongod stop` then `sudo service mongod start`

Note, please be careful that if you have any data in the old location and you want to keep, you'll need to stop the MongoDB service first, manually move the files and then start the service again.