# Configure MongoDB in EC2 with EBS (SSD Volume)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am bit confused about !
MongoDB is required for my one of application. Should I go with MongoDB Atlas
OR EC2 built-in MongoDB (by the way I have choose this).

If you go with EC2 built-in MongoDB, then my next question is, let say any instance EC2 of type eg - "MAD5 LARGE" how can i store all my DB data in separate EBS Volume ( Which does not delete in EC2 Termination ), which is not built-in EC2 Storage.

So that if any time I want to terminate my instance, I can do it any time without any worries and attach the volume with new instance  ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can choose not to delete your `Root EBS volume` when you terminate the `EC2 instance`.

[image]

Second you can Attach additional `EBS volumes` to your `EC2 Instance`, which wont get deleted when you terminate the `EC2 instance`

Comment: Both points are totally correct but my question is how can I configure my MongoDB database to additional EBS volumes (acc. to your second point) , as ec2 will store database in default ebs volume so that I can prevent my database.

Comment: Use --dbpath argument.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have attached the EBS volume, you need to **mount** the newly created volume with Linux OS.

Then you need to configure the MongoDB `dbpath` in `/etc/mongod.conf` file.

You can check the step-by-step process [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534502/set-storage-location-of-mongodb-installed-on-aws-ec2-instance-to-ebs-storage-an/67157224#67157224) in my answer.